# How do I get the tf and idf score from a Solr query?

Tags: java, apache, search, solr, lucene

Following Solr documentations (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Function+Queries and others) I should just put idf(fieldname, 'term') as I do with termfreq(fieldname, 'term') in the field list. However, whenever I try this I get an exception as:

```
org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: No live SolrServers available to handle this request
```

By looking at the logs I could find:

```
null:java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: requires a TFIDFSimilarity (such as ClassicSimilarity)
```

And I have no idea what those are. Also when I use ***debugQuery=on*** it shows me, along with a lot of other things, the idf value for the document as:

```
4.406719 = idf, computed as log(1 + (docCount - docFreq + 0.5) / (docFreq + 0.5))
```

What should I do to fix these errors or to get desired tf and idf value for a term?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add following line in your "managed-schema" where similarity tag is commented at the end of the schema

```
<similarity class="solr.ClassicSimilarityFactory"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had run into the same issue and found this chrome extension -

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/solr-query-debugger/gmpkeiamnmccifccnbfljffkcnacmmdl?hl=en

It is really helpful in breaking down "explain" and will display the value of idf for you.