# use tf func in fl parameter got exception

Tags: solr

I use solr 7.1.0, and I want get the tf, idf values with in a query, so a send the query with:

```
http://192.168.0.127:8983/solr/law/select?fl=tf(content,2005)&q=*:*&wt=xml
```

but, I got an exception:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>

<lst name="responseHeader">
  <bool name="zkConnected">true</bool>
  <int name="status">500</int>
  <int name="QTime">12</int>
  <lst name="params">
    <str name="q">*:*</str>
    <str name="fl">tf(content, 2005)</str>
    <str name="wt">xml</str>
    <str name="_">1511167922616</str>
  </lst>
</lst>
<lst name="error">
  <lst name="metadata">
    <str name="error-class">org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException</str>
    <str name="root-error-class">org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException</str>
  </lst>
  <str name="msg">Error from server at http://192.168.0.127:8983/solr/law_shard2_replica_n2: Server Error

request: http://192.168.0.127:8983/solr/law_shard2_replica_n2/select</str>
  <str name="trace">org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at http://192.168.0.127:8983/solr/law_shard2_replica_n2: Server Error

request: http://192.168.0.127:8983/solr/law_shard2_replica_n2/select
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:626)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:253)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:242)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.request(SolrClient.java:1219)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpShardHandler.lambda$submit$0(HttpShardHandler.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at com.codahale.metrics.InstrumentedExecutorService$InstrumentedRunnable.run(InstrumentedExecutorService.java:176)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ExecutorUtil.java:188)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
</str>
  <int name="code">500</int>
</lst>
</response>
```

is some jar library need copy to libs dir? or something I missing?

BTW, the docfreq and termfreq is working.

Comment: Check the server side log for Solr to get the actual error - but try `tf(content, '2005')` - i.e. with quotes around the term you're looking up (.. as that's how it's used in the documentation at least, but Solr usually accepts both forms..)

Comment: log show me the actual exception:
    2017-11-20 09:48:57.810 ERROR (qtp947679291-18) [c:law s:shard2 r:core_node4 x:law_shard2_replica_n2] o.a.s.s.HttpSolrCall null:java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: requires a TFIDFSimilarity (such as ClassicSimilarity)

I use bin/solr -c start a solrcloud service, after set 
    <similarity class="solr.BM25SimilarityFactory"/> in configsets/_default/config/managed-schema, I still get this exception.

Answer (score 2):

[this is the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43692041/how-do-i-get-the-tf-and-idf-score-from-a-solr-query), add the following into schema.xml or managed-schema (solr cloud).

```
<similarity class="solr.ClassicSimilarityFactory"/>
```

BM25Similarity is not sub-class of TFIDFSimilarity, so solr.BM25SimilarityFactory is not correct.

Thank you [MatsLindh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/137650/matslindh)!